# How to hide/remove the import/export buttons on Preferences dialog in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a little experience using Activities with Eclipse RCP to hide plugin UI components, but this one is stumping me. I used the Eclipse Plug-in Selection Spy to try and see which plugin provides the import/export buttons at the bottom of the default Preferences page, and it seems to point to `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`. At least, that's what comes up when I can actually click on the Preferences dialog. When I do `Alt + Shift + F1` and try to click on the Export button, for example, the cursor turns back into a regular pointer and the Plug-in Spy window comes up empty when I click.

The class that provides the default Preferences page is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog`. This class extends `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog`, which has a method that adds the import/export buttons to the dialog upon calling `open()`.

So, I looked in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plugin to try and find something to put in my `activityPatternBinding` that would hide these buttons. I tried using

```xml
<activityPatternBinding
    activityId="my_hidden_activity"
    isEqualityPattern="true"
    pattern="org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.PreferencesImportWizard">
</activityPatternBinding>
```

to prevent the import class from being shown and maybe that would stop the button from showing up, but that did not work.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these icons without completely rewriting the default Preferences dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only hide items if the code that creates them calls the activity manager to check if they are being filtered - usually by calling `WorkbenchActivityHelper.filterItem`.

The import / export code in `FilteredPreferenceDialog` doesn't make this call so it cannot be removed with activities. I don't see any way to suppress these buttons.